# Using node cli tool as a library (trimp3)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I have found the following library, which I would like to use in my own nodejs file: https://github.com/kyr0/trimp3

However, it is a cli tool, and I would like to use it as a library.

How could I use this in my own nodejs code, and use it programmatically, (that is, without executing it as a cli tool from my nodejs file, but straight in node).

I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Look at the actual code. `trimp3.js` is a very thin wrapper around `libtrimp3.js`, which you can import and use as you like with a bit of modification/monkey patching. And even *that* is mostly a thin wrapper around `ffmpeg`.

Comment: I looked at it, but I can't figure out how I would actually call it from my nodejs file and pass down arguments. In trimp3.js it is jus called with `require(path.resolve(__filename, '../libtrimp3.js')).cli();` if i understand correctly? But how would I do this in a simple nodejs file, with a 'normal' library call?

Comment: The only things that actually do anything there are the functions `trim` and `calcTimes`, the rest is just for the CLI usage. I'd simply copy those few lines into my own project and adapt them as necessary. Absolutely no need to depend on that library.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment that you could just copy the code into your own module and use it as needed, but if you really want to add this dependency,  you could install it locally

```
$ npm install trimp3 --save
```

and then require it with its full path to libtrimp3.js like so:

```
const trimp = require('./node_modules/trimp3/libtrimp3.js')
```

You'll need to adjust that path based on where you're calling it to make sure you have the right relative path.

** UPDATE **

Based on comment, it's a good point that the library is expecting information to come in through the CLI. That's actually not hard to fake either, though, as process.argv is just an array, though if you're using it for other things you may have to account for that.  Prior to requiring trimp3 (since the parsing of process.argv happens when the file is loaded, sadly), your calling code would have to set the array to something trimp3 expects.  It's slicing the array at 2, so it's going to skip the first two items in the array and the remaining array will be parsed as follows:

```
mp3In: argv[0],
mp3Out: argv[1],
beginTime: argv[2],
endTime: argv[3]
```

So if you were to set `process.argv = ['', '', 'path/to/input', 'path/to/output', 'beginTime', 'endTime']` prior to requiring trimp3, you'd be in the ballpark.

All this goes back to my initial agreement with the comments that it's better to probably *not* use this library, but instead learn from it to build your own module.

Comment: If you look at the code, it is pretty hardcoded to assume invocation from a CLI, exclusively using `argv` to read arguments. So it's not *that* easy…

Comment: @deceze updated to account for your comment, please let me know if that resolves your concern.